# Who was this girl who can manipulate birds?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, comic-adaptation, x-men-apocalypse

In **X-Men: Apocalypse** we get to know that Magneto has started a family and has a wife and daughter.
Now this newly established daughter shows the power to make birds attack the police before when she died by accident. I have seen and read many X-Men works but never encountered a mutant who can do this and Magneto doesn’t even had any children in comics **[after the latest retcon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122454/why-was-quicksilver-vulnerable-to-scarlet-witchs-curse-in-the-decimation-comics)**. He nearly got two daughters, Wanda Maximoff who had the power of magic and second Polaris, who had a similar power to Magneto. But both were not his daughter and neither did their power match this girl.

So who was she and did she resemble any of her counterparts from comics? Or is she a nod to Polaris or Wanda?

Comment: Just a note, I think she could manipulate more animals, because in her earlier scene, she was petting a deer.

Comment: @Zikato that will be a speculation till we know details as petting a deer can be normal and i even forget any such scene ;D

Comment: And i thought she would resurrect -_-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nina is not a character in the X-Men comics, but may be a renamed version of Magneto's first daughter, Anya. [Magda](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/magda-eisenhardt/4005-45372/) was the name of Magneto's first wife in the comics, and his wife in the film *X-Men: Apocalypse*. In the comics she was the mother of Anya, who died tragically in a fire. Magento's reaction, similar to the movie, cause Magda to be scared and run away. This was just after becoming pregnant with the twin brother and sister (Pietro and Wanda, also known as Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch), so Magneto never knew.

Incidentally, I think that Polaris is still Magneto's daughter in the current Marvel comics continuity. Only Pietro and Wanda were ret-conned to no longer be his children during the AXIS event.

Comment: Didn't he just faked being father of Polaris and Polaris was responsible for the death of her real parents?

Comment: @AnkitSharma That was her real mother who died in the plane crash, but the man was her step-father. She thought he was her real father at the time, though, since she only confirmed that Magneto was her real father years later.

Comment: I know quite less and it is too confusing. Anyway did Anya was also mutant with similar power?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I don't think there was any mention of Anya having any mutant powers.

Comment: K, seems like more reasonable answer then.