# Magneto's Children in Avengers and X-Men

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch are Magneto's children right.. Now in the Avengers's movies both of them appear not as mutants but the enhanced or whatever. and in the X-Men movies both of them appear, or atleast I think Eric's daughter in the X-Men Apocalypse movie was Scarlet Witch.

So my question: Is there a reason they killed Quicksilver in the avengers movies (in which no body ever dies) and Scarlet Witch or Magneto's daughter in the X-Men Movies.. Was there like a rights issue or something that they couldn't be shared among the two series?

Comment: See [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/33984/27264) and [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13512/27264)

Comment: Girl in Apocalypse had nothing in common to Scarlet Witch except same father, refer [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53667/who-was-this-girl-who-can-manipulate-birds)

Comment: *Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch are Magneto's children right..*, actually... [no](https://www.newsarama.com/22948-did-marvel-comics-just-solve-the-mcu-s-scarlet-witch-quicksilver-father-problem-spoilers.html).

Comment: Quickly and simplified said: Disney doesn't have the X-Men rights (Fox does), so they can't say they are Magneto children. They did manage to use the two characters though. It's two different universe (in Movies), not in Comics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Isn't the Quicksilver from Avengers 2 the same as the Quicksilver from X-Men: Days of Future Past?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33984/isnt-the-quicksilver-from-avengers-2-the-same-as-the-quicksilver-from-x-men-da)

Answer (score 4):

Due to a contractual situation Marvel are not allowed to use "Mutants" in their movies, and 20th Century Fox are not allowed to use The Avengers characters in theirs.

How this is exactly detailed in the licensing agreements I'm not sure is entirely clear, but what is apparent is that there are some 'grey area' characters, including Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch.

In the MCU, the Maximoff twins are not mutants, and they are not children of Magneto. Magneto does not exist in the MCU.

In the X-Men movie franchise, Peter Maximoff is a mutant, and is clearly aware that he is the son of Magneto, but chooses not the share that information.  There is also no mention at all of a twin sister.

Nina, the much younger daughter of Magneto, is clearly not Peter's twin, isn't called Wanda nor does she appear to share any powers with Scarlet Witch.  I don't think we're meant to assume that she is that character.

Why did they choose to kill off Quicksilver in Avengers - Age of Ultron?
 There's no indication that this was due to a rights problem as there has been no dispute over Age of Ulton or the two X-Men movies with Quicksilver.  They are clearly in a position where both organizations can use the Quicksilver character.

I think the character was killed off for plot purposes.  He is a 'second tier' character in importance, having only appeared in post credits scene prior to the movie.  The Maximoff's coming over to 'the good guys' side and his (eventually friendly) rivalry with Hawkeye is an key character arc in Age of Ultron.

Comment: Just to help support this, SPOILERS AHEAD: Agents of Shield had rights to Marvel's Von Stuckers and now The Gifted (which is still an X-Men 20th Cent. Fox production apart of X-Men franchise, still had to have Marvel Entert. co-produce on the series) does also feature characters the Struckers, in which upcoming press releases tell us their name still relates to (some version) of Von Struckers, despite that AoS (Marvel property) just also used them.

Answer (score -1):

Quicksilver falls into the category of a bunch of characters that can be used by either studio. I think marvel killed him off because x men's silver did a far better job and really there are several dozen Avengers left to use.